# How to create multiple TFRecord files instead of making a big one and then splitting it up?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm dealing with quite big time series dataset, one that prepared as `SequenceExample`s is then written to a `TFRecord`. This results in a quite large file (over 100GB) but I'd like to have it stored in chunks. I've tried:

```
file = '/path/to/tf_record_0.tfrecords'
file_index = 0

   for record in dataset:
      # fill the time series window, prepare the sequence_example, etc.

      if os.path.exists(file) and os.path.getsize(file) > 123456789:
         file = file.replace(str(file_index), str(file_index + 1))
         file_index += 1

            with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(file) as writer:
               writer.write(sequence_example.SerializeToString())
```

...but since `TFRecordWriter` opens files like Python's `open(file, mode='w')` it overwrites itself every time it enters the `with` block (apart from it being really ugly solution) and from what I've read there's no way to change that behavior.
Changing path to `file` inside `with` block obviously throws an error.

So my question is, is there a way to create next `TFRecord` file when current reaches certain size while looping and working with my dataset? And is there a benefit of having smaller `TFRecord` files anyway when I'm not dealing with any type of bottleneck apart from lack of system memory? If I'm correct Tensorflow can read it from the disk without issues (although there might be other reasons one would prefer to have multiple files anyway).

One thing I can think of is creating some sort of buffer in a `list` for ready-to-be-saved sequences and creating/saving to `TFRecord` once that buffer reaches some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a data generator to create my TF records, in my case, I followed almost the same as suggested by the previous answer, here is my code:

```
tfrecord_filename = 'test_record_{}.tfrecords'
file_index_count = 0

base_path = 'image_path'

for index in range(2): # Number of splits
    writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_filename.format(index))

    serialized_features_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
           generator, output_types=tf.string, output_shapes=())

     writer.write(serialized_features_dataset)
```

I added the following code to the generator:

```
def generator():
    for folder in os.listdir(base_path):
        images = glob.glob(base_path+folder+ '/*.jpg')
    
        partition_factor = len(images) // 2 # split number
        partition_images = images[int(partition_factor*index):int(partition_factor*(index+1))]

    for image in partition_images:
        yield serialize_images(image, folder) # this method is where I parse the images into records
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Tensorflow 2.1.0**,
perhaps you could try this approach when dealing in this kind of problem.

```
file = '/content/tmp/records/tf_record_{}.tfrecords'
file_index_count = 0

file_limit = 10
for index in range(file_limit):
  tfrecord_writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(file.format(file_index_count))
  ####
  # Add your Preprocessing Codes here
  # ie. split/divide array into 10 parts
  # ie. test_in = array[int(10*index): int(10*(index+1))]
  ####
  serial_test_in = serialize_example(test_in) 
  tfrecord_writer.write(serial_test_in)
  ###
  # Add your conditional for file index
  # ie. if size < totalsize
  ###
  file_index_count += 1
```

This generates **10** files of **TF Records** as shown in this screenshot.

[image: 10_files of tfrecords]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TFRecordWriter overwrites every time and you must decide in advance what to write to a TFRecord file. It is recommended to have TFRecord file of size ~100MB (see [tensorflow performance guide](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Eguide/performance/performance_guide)). You can calculate a mean of how much space (X) a record of **SequenceExample** occupies by writing a test TFRecord file containing 100 examples and dividing file size with 100. Then, you would write at a time 100 * 1024 * 1024 / X records in the new TFRecord file. This is a snippet code for splitting a TFRecord into more:

```
large_file_name = os.path.join("path", "to", "large_file.tfrecord")
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(large_file_name)

# find out how many records you have in the large TFRecord file
largeTFRecordCount = sum(1 for _ in dataset)
X = 10000 # calculated sequence_example size in bytes
exampleNumberInTFRecord = int(100 * 1024 * 1024 / X)
recordCounter = 0
while recordCounter < largeTFRecordCount / exampleNumberInTFRecord:
    recordsToSkip = int(recordCounter * exampleNumberInTFRecord)
    newDataset = dataset.skip(recordsToSkip)
    # check if the dataset still has exampleNumberInTFRecord in it
    if recordsToSkip + exampleNumberInTFRecord > largeTFRecordCount:
        recordsToTake = largeTFRecordCount - recordsToSkip
    newDataset = newDataset.take(exampleNumberInTFRecord)
    file = os.path.join("path", "to", "tf_record_" + str(recordCounter) + ".tfrecord")
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(file) as writer:
        for record in newDataset:
            writer.write(tf.io.serialize_tensor(record).numpy())
    recordCounter += 1
```